# Background-Workers in Ionic 4 vs. Ionic 3

Tags: android, performance, ionic4, backgroundworker

I have a requirement to use a backgroundworker for polling notifications in an existing Ionic 3 app. Now is the question if it is a better way to use Ionic 4 to realize background workers. I have heard that in Ionic 4 the backgroundworker are more oriented at angular concept.

Have anybody experience with backgroundworkers in Ionic 4 ? How is the performance on device ?
Is it worth the change to Ionic 4 ?

Comment: hey Micha do you mean Service Worker or Web Workers?

Comment: I need a functionality to poll notifications in the background also when app is not in foreground. Is ionic 4 here a better solution.

Comment: So notifications can be native functionality (iOS or Android) and can be web push notifications. There is no polling in modern implementations only push based. With Ionic you can get native notifications via plugins such as google's FCM - https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm or this one: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push. I think you need to try one or another approach and then if faced challenges - ask mroe specific question

Comment: Thanks for infos - I will check